# Extending nodes net.Socket class

Tags: node.js, typescript, class, sockets

I have a node app written in Typescript that creates a `net.Socket` to connect to a SMTP server. I created a custom class that extends the built in `net.Socket` class with a few methods unique to my program.

I also have a node server to receive SMTP commands and respond to them. As you know `server.on('connection', function(socket){...}` returns a `net.Socket`. Is there a way I can use my extended Socket class for this socket to share some functionality between incoming and outgoing sockets?

Comment: Possibly, but it would be easier to just wrap the server.on method and use composition instead of inheritance

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the server is [hard-wired to construct a `net.Socket`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/cdb359840c9537e460b1bf0536fc36ec5fe2db2d/lib/net.js#L1505).  I don't see any way you can modify or replace the `Socket` constructor, but you can monkey-patch additional methods onto the prototype and declare them for TypeScript.  Another option to consider would be to make your own server class that wraps a `net.Server` and produces sockets that wrap the `net.Socket`s, although this would be a lot more work.